# Max permissible length for string field

Tags: marketo

I have a string custom field which captures the page's url from which the lead is generated. When calling the create/update lead, I am seeing this error message:

```
Value for field 'page_url' exceeds max length
```

What is the max permissible length for string custom field?
The api call is failing for strings exceeding 400 characters in length.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep URLs under 2000 characters, they'll work in virtually any combination of client and server software.

Comment: updated the question to indicated the the lengths at which the API call is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The types and their lengths etc are listed at
[this url](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/faq/field-types/)
There is a type called URL, which is what I wills start using.